# Was Prophet Muhammad ascension to heavens (Mirage or Miraj) Real?

Tags: islamic-events, miraj

There are two school of thought on Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) visit to the Heavens (sky) and meet God. One school says

1. This happened in real (this is more authentic).
2. This was shown to the prophet in a dream only

My question is now that we know Earth is round, there are no 7 skies, there is no air above certain altitude where you can breath, you cannot survive without space suite and oxygen and you cannot survive at -273C temperature and there were no witnesses. + Prophet Muhammad never said anything that would have proved the visit otherwise. For example he never pointed that the earth was round, he never said anything about the stars, the moon. This would mean, in plain scientific terms, this was just an imagination and nothing close to reality. Muslims often explain things in Quran logically and scientifically. If I go by logic, this event by all means says it is false. But it is an important event. That is when 5 prayers/day were imposed. How can I convince myself that this happened in real, while all the odds are against it. Did it happen in real?

Comment: "How you can convince yourself ..." sounds like an advice request and is rather off-topic.

Answer (score 10):

Your statements about earth being round, oxygen and temperature are correct. Indeed a man by himself can not travel in space without life support *as of now according to established science*.

The fact that Prophet (P.B.U.H) went on Miraj is in the following [verse in Quran](http://quran.com/17/1):

> **Exalted is He who took His Servant** by night from al-Masjid al-Haram to
>   al-Masjid al- Aqsa, whose surroundings We have blessed, to show him of
>   Our signs. Indeed, He is the Hearing, the Seeing.

Here Allah (S.W.T) mentions that Prophet went on Miraj but **not how** he was taken there. We can not say something is wrong according to science unless we know how that something happened correct?

And we're missing a point here. Prophet (P.B.U.H) *did not go on Miraj by himself*. Allah (S.W.T) took him there. We are talking about The Creator of the universe here. He who has created the universe is not bound by the laws of physics that he has designed for us.

> Certainly, Allah has power over all things.

He who can bring Adam (P.B.U.H) from Heaven to earth without space suit can very well take a man from earth and ascend him up to sky without life support.

If I write a computer program and restrict its behavior based on certain inputs it doesn't mean I can not modify it or add provisions in it to behave differently when I'm using it.

And Allah (S.W.T) knows best.